# How can start the app after the permission is granted?

Tags: java, android, audio, recording

well, I'm creating an app for recording audio, and for that, I give two permissions to the program which it works perfectly. and I want to play and audio when the user gets the permission granted. but my code plays the audio at the same time of permission prompt. can anyone help me, please?

this is the functions I used for getting the permissions:
private void requestPermission() {

```
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, RECORD_AUDIO}, RequestPermissionCode);

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RequestPermissionCode:
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {

                boolean StoragePermission = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                boolean RecordPermission = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                if (StoragePermission && RecordPermission) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Permission Denied",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }

            break;
    }
}

public boolean checkPermission() {

    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), RECORD_AUDIO);

    return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
```

and here where I used the functions and played the audio:

if (!checkPermission()) {

```
        requestPermission();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (isFirstRun) {

            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.instruction);

            mediaPlayer1.start();
           // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "First run", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            getSharedPreferences("Preference", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).apply();

        }
```

Comment: you need to make requestPermission have a callback method when it's done and then run.

Answer (score 1):

You make 2 async tasks : requestPermission() and play audio.
Do not synchronize code with Thread.sleep().

```
if(!checkPermission()){
    //it is async call, you never know when result come.
    requestPermission();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
        final int requestCode,
        @NonNull final String[] permissions,
        @NonNull final int[] grantResults
) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (permissionGranted()) {
        playMusic();
    }
}
```

With this aproach you do not need 'isFirsRun' variable.

Comment: the "isFirsRun" is used when a user installed the app for the first time then Audio will be played to give some instructions.